# DateFormatter gives one hour earlier

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have a problem with dateformatter. I want parse date, but I always get one hour earlier

The image is from http://nsdateformatter.com/ where I tried parse date which I put to date in a result, but I always get an hour earlier. I need get `18:18:46`, but I always get `17:18:46`

[image]

My code which doesn't work:

```
extension Date {
   func getString() -> String {
        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations[0])

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.calendar = calendar
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d.M.yyyy, HH:mm:ss"

        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
   }
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You are in the UTC+1 timezone. There should be a difference of one hour between local time and UTC.

Comment: How can I change it?

Comment: Do you want to display the date to the user in their local time or UTC time (or some other timezone)?

Comment: I want to display user's local time

Comment: The code you posted already does that. By default, a `DateFormatter` works in the user's local time.

Comment: If you can see the picture which I posted there it doesn't work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183741/discussion-between-david-kadlcek-and-rmaddy).

Comment: You've provided no details about that picture and how it relates to the code you posted. Until you do, no one can help. [Edit] your question with more details.

Comment: Your updated question is still unclear. You seem to have a date of `18:18:46` in UTC time. You then correctly convert that to `17:18:46` local time (which is UTC+1 in the Czech Republic at the moment). Then you state it's an hour off. It's supposed to be an hour off given where you live. Please clarify why you think this is incorrect behavior. Are you confused by the results in the picture or something about your code?